# UITextView custom spelling and autocorrect

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autocomplete, uitextview, spell-checking

I want to make an iOS text editor for a certain rare human language, and I want it to support my own spell checking and autocorrect systems for that language.

**In iOS, is it possible to get UITextView to use a custom spell checker and autocorrect system, rather than those of the system's current locale?** Or do I have to resort to creating a text view from scratch using Core Text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think there’s a way to actually change the spell-checking mechanism of `UITextView`.

A good approach would be to set your `UITextView`’s `spellCheckingType` to `UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo`, so system spell checking is disabled—then use an attributed string to draw the spell error marker on the text yourself, using your own spell-checking class/engine to find spelling errors.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13113412/175048) on how to use attributed strings.