# Underline text in a UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextview

How can I underline text in a `UITextView`. I understand that I would need to create a subclass of `UITextView`, but what would go under `drawRect:`?

Thanks.

Comment: please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927810/uitextview-underlined-text/30973554#30973554

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to use `NSAttributedString` as follows and set in `UITextView`. This works for iOS6.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Some String"];
[attString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName 
                   value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTUnderlineStyleSingle] 
                   range:(NSRange){0,[attString length]}];
```

For more info on `NSAttributedString` check this [How do you use NSAttributedString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring)

For eg:-

```
textView.attributedText = attString;
```

From [apple documentation on UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html),

> In iOS 6 and later, this class supports multiple text styles through
>   use of the attributedText property. (Styled text is not supported in
>   earlier versions of iOS.) Setting a value for this property causes the
>   text view to use the style information provided in the attributed
>   string. You can still use the font, textColor, and textAlignment
>   properties to set style attributes, but those properties apply to all
>   of the text in the text view.

### **attributedText:**

The styled text displayed by the text view.

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSAttributedString *attributedText
```

**Discussion:** This property is nil by default. Assigning a new value to this property also replaces the value of the text property with the same string data, albeit without any formatting information. In addition, assigning a new a value updates the values in the font, textColor, and textAlignment properties so that they reflect the style information starting at location 0 in the attributed string.

Comment: Hi, when you say 'set in UITextView', how do you mean? Could you post an example of how to do this?

Comment: @d3v3l0p3r101, Updated my answer. Check it.

Comment: Thanks - really appreciated! I'm getting this error with the NSAttributedString code though: http://pixelbit.in/KV2u.

Comment: I added the coretext framework, the same issue still occurs :(

Comment: I found the issue - it had to be an NSMutableAttributedString

Comment: Oops! I missed that. Even I was thinking why that error came for you where as I can see that it is available in the class. I will update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Just one last question - is there any way I can undo this underlining in the UITextView? Like textView.attributedText = nil? Except that also removes all the text...

Comment: You can use - (void)removeAttribute:(NSString *)name range:(NSRange)aRange similar to the above addAttribute method and set it on textView.attributedText = attString; again. Rest of the code will remain same except for addAttribute change to removeAttribute. If this answer is helpful, can you please accept it. :)

Comment: Any alternative option for iOS 5.0 ?

Comment: This can actually be written a bit more concisely:     `self.textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World" attributes:@{ NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) }];`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to avoid having to include CoreText, you can utilize an attributed string with this attribute:

```
@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)}
```

Answer (score 8):

If this is static text, you can underline it in Interface Builder. Make sure to make the text 'Attributed' first by selecting 'Attributed' in the drop down menu:

[image]

Comment: and open fonts through the context menu: select the text, then right-click and choose fonts from the menu.

Answer (score 2):

```
textViewMessage.linkTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blueColor], NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format your text (with underlined words, links, colored words...) I suggest you to use [FTCoreText](https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTCoreText)

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)underline:(id)sender
{
    NSDictionary *underlineAttribute = @{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)};
    texts.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:texts.text
                                                           attributes:underlineAttribute];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use "kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName" or "kCTUnderlineStyleSingle"
Now you must do it like this:

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Text"];
[attString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                  value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)
                  range:(NSRange){0,[attString length]}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iOS 6 then you can use the `attributedText` attribute of **UITextView**. Apply underline formatting to the text. You can also set the `typingAttributes` property to ensure the text that the user types has a specific set of formatting if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [CoreText](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html). A Basic tutorial is [here on raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [MFUnderlinedTextView](https://github.com/mfoxstudio/MFUnderlinedTextView/), it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it using Swift 5:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myTextView.text ?? "")
myTextView.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle.rawValue): NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue] as [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]?
myTextView.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.
As my UITextView if for inserting text, I created an extension function as bellow.

```
extension UITextView {

  func underlined() {
    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(1.0)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - 5, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: 1)
    border.borderWidth = width
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    style.lineSpacing = 15
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : style, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.darkGray, NSAttributedString.Key.font :  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)]
    self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: self.text, attributes: attributes)
  }

}
```

The border is drawling the line and the style is adding the spacing between the lines. 
Usage in your UIView custom layout:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.dateAndTimeInput.underlined()
  }
```

[Image with the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LFYC.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
       let someString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your String", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20), NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
        someStringTextView.attributedText = titleAT
```

U can just give your string a bunch of attributes like bold, underlined etc.

Answer (score -3):

To underline a text, you have to go where you can select copy, cut , delete options there are now more options like B/I/U( bold, italic, underline).  Choose this option and this is it. And to unable it, choose underline option again.